# Trouble with visualizer.pl

Tags: state, visualizer, multi-agent, discrete-space

I'm trying to use visualizer.pl to visualize the dynamics of multi-state system

my function file:

```
f1 := x2
f2 := x1+x2*x3
f3 := x3^2+x1+x2+1
```

I used the following command as mentioned in "readme.txt"

```
perl visualizer.pl -p 1.txt 3 3
```

since prime := 3 and num_nodes :=3

but I got this error

educ@educ-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/visualizer$ perl visualizer.pl -p 1.txt 3 3

Errors found in the input file. See below for description:

---

ERROR: Incorrect start of function declaration in function 1.

Errors with input file..ending program at visualizer.pl line 162, > line 1.

State Space Visualizer
Version 1.0 beta
-------------------------------------
The State Space Visualizer is a tool for the visualization of the dynamics of multi-state, discrete models of biological networks.

More information about package:

https://web.archive.org/web/20110815084457/http://dvd.vbi.vt.edu/tutorial.html

https://web.archive.org/web/20120320172453if_/http://dvd.vbi.vt.edu/visualizer.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `=` to separate your functions, and remove spaces around the `=`. Your input file should thus be:

```
f1=x2
f2=x1+x2*x3
f3=x3^2+x1+x2+1
```

I know that it's not consistent with the `readme`, but it's consistent with the content of `visualizer.pl`, and it works.

If, once that's done, the script `visualizer.pl` fails with:

> sh: 1: kghostview: not found

You can fix it by installing ghostview (`sudo apt install gv` on Debian), and replacing the line `system("kghostview out.ps &");` by `system("gv out.ps &");` at the end of `visualizer.pl`.